# Satellite image anomaly

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, satellites, image-processing

This is a satellite image of somewhere in West Texas:

[image]

See the localized Red-Green-Blue feature on the road?
What could have caused this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about satellite photography, but ground-mapping cameras on aircraft often re-construct color images from sequential red, green, and blue images. The re-construction algorithm takes into account the motion of the aircraft, but it can not compensate for the motion of vehicles on the ground or, of other aircraft within the camera's field of view. That bright spot probably is a vehicle that was moving along the road. It was in different locations when the red, green, and blue images were snapped.

E.g., This photo of another airplane that was caught by a Google mapping aircraft:

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/52284045645387713/